# TFS iterating over all git branches when using Gitversiontask

Tags: tfs, msbuild-task, build-server, gitversion

I have a Visual Studio solution that contains 48 C# projects. Now, that I automatically want to version all projects, I just added the Nuget Package for GitVersionTask to all projects (Version 4.0.0-beta0012). When I build the solution locally, everything works fine. The freshly built binaries contain the version info generated by gitversion.

But when I try to build via our TFS build server then, it's doing something with the branches. Here is some squashed output from the build log:

```
2018-03-14T14:34:38.0434047Z UpdateAssemblyInfo:
2018-03-14T14:34:38.0434047Z   INFO [03/14/18 15:34:38:04] Applicable build agent found: 'VsoAgent'.
2018-03-14T14:34:38.0434047Z   INFO [03/14/18 15:34:38:04] Branch from build environment: refs/heads/sprint022/add-gitversion
2018-03-14T14:34:38.0590291Z   INFO [03/14/18 15:34:38:05] Begin: Normalizing git directory for branch 'refs/heads/sprint022/add-gitversion'
2018-03-14T14:34:38.3402986Z     INFO [03/14/18 15:34:38:34] One remote found (origin -> 'https://link-to-our-git-repo-on-tfs').
2018-03-14T14:34:38.3559076Z     INFO [03/14/18 15:34:38:35] Skipping fetching, if GitVersion does not calculate your version as expected you might need to allow fetching or use dynamic repositories
2018-03-14T14:34:38.4652918Z     INFO [03/14/18 15:34:38:46] Updating local branch refs/heads/sprint022/add-gitversion to point at e8d694a08080c8117b9c6cf93032c16057b05dab
2018-03-14T14:34:38.7621669Z     INFO [03/14/18 15:34:38:76] Skipping update of 'refs/remotes/origin/3620_Error_Handling_Refactoring' as it already matches the remote ref.
```

...This last message "Skipping update of ... as it already matches the remote ref" is being repeated for EVERY branch that is on our remote repository. As this is quite a large amount of branches, this takes nearly one minute for one project in the solution. So, for the whole solution we would come near one full hour of time for this.

I already spent a lot of time researching for this, but I still could not find anything helpful on the web.

Does somebody have an idea why the TFS does this as part of the solution build, while the local Visual Studio build does not do it?

Comment: Can you version the projects successfully except spending more time to do that?

Comment: Yes, I just rechecked it: The version info is properly generated, but still the time taken is unreasonable.

Comment: For Local build with VS, the sources have already been downloaded from the repo. But for TFS, it will get the sources from Git repo during the build process. Generally it will take more time to do that.

Comment: Are you sure? Before building the solution, we have a "Get Sources" build step which is pulling the changes from the remote repository. After that, we just have the "Build Solution" step. I don't think why this should even access the remote, because everything is already pulled

Comment: I mean get sources will spend more tiem. How did you build the solution locally? build in VS directly or via command line? You can try to build the solution in command line then check the logs to compare with the TFS build log.  Build in TFS is actually calling the msbuild command.

Comment: I did some more tests. Building the solution locally with MSBuild also works well - the resulting assemblys are properly versioned and there is nothing as described above, build is fast as expected. I even tried to use the same git version like the build server, still, everything is fine.

Comment: @PaulM Did you ever figure this out? I have 71 projects in my solution but luckily fewer remote branches, but what used to take about 1.5 mins to build with Jenkins now take 5+ minutes. Not a dealbreaker but definitely an irritation.